# Add a link for icon in CSS :before

Tags: css, url, hyperlink, icons, pseudo-element

I want to add a link in pure CSS.

Tried to add the `url` in `background` as the code below. Unfortunately, it does not work.

```css
.fa-home:before {
    font-size: 2rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
    background: url(https://example.com);
}
```

The icon looks like:

[image]

Is any ways to achieve this just using CSS? (Assume having no access to the control of HTML and JS.)

Comment: there is no way with CSS

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it using CSS.

CSS - Cascading Style Sheets. It describes how HTML elements are to be displayed on screen, paper, or in other media. In simple words - HTML creates elements like images, links and CSS add a style.

Using url in background is similar to `src=""` attribute in img tag. You provide the url to the image you want to use as background image.